# How to remove username and password2 fields from form errors

Tags: django, message

I have a problem with these fields in their output to the html template. I need to output only error text without field data in the `Messages` function. [error on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7BEg.png)

Create messages in views.py
`messages.error(request, form.errors)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.contrib import messages

def your_view(request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        do_something
    else:
       error_text = '<ul style="display:flex;'\
              'flex-direction:column;list-style-type:none;"'
       for msg_list in form.errors.values():
           for msg in msg_list:
               error_text += f'<li>{msg}</li>'
       error_text += '</ul>'
    messages.error(request, mark_safe(error_text))
    # write your other code
```

Also use `safe` filter in your template:

```
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
      <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
        {{ message|safe }}
          <button  class="close">x</button>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
```